# Appending nodes of tree to a python list

Tags: python, list, tree

I have a tree like this:

```
         A 
      /  |   \
    B    C    D
  /  \   |   / | \
 E    F  G  H  I  J
```

and I am trying to append the nodes of the tree to an empty list
such that the list looks like:

```
[[A], [B, C, D], [E, F, G, H, I, J]]
```

Suppose that I have a root_node A and I don't know how deep my tree is.
How can I append nodes from the tree to an empty list in the above-mentioned format?

I tried breadth first search, but my list length is way longer than than the
depth of the tree.

Comment: You can append anything to a list by using its `append` method. If the resulting list is too long then you have used `append` too often. Or you have appended to the wrong list.

Comment: I can use append but my problem is  the length of list should match the depth of tree

Comment: if i use append naively my list will look like: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, I, J] and I want my list to look like [ [A], [B, C, D],  [E, F, G, I, J] ]

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't think you read my question properly.

Comment: Why does `B` have two child nodes, `C` have one child, and `D` have three child nodes. There doesn't seem to be a consistent logic regarding the structure of this tree. How can you know when to start a new level?

Comment: @MarkMeyer well my tree is such that a node can have any number of child or not. Like a  folder could contain any number of folder and folders in folder could contain any number of folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a Node implementation like:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Node({self.name})'
```

You can create your nodes and arrange a graph with:

```
nodes = {letter: Node(letter) for letter in 'ABCDEFGHIJ'}

nodes['A'].children.extend([nodes['B'], nodes['C'], nodes['D']])
nodes['B'].children.extend([nodes['E'], nodes['F']])
nodes['C'].children.extend([nodes['G']])
nodes['D'].children.extend([nodes['H'], nodes['I'], nodes['J']])
```

Now you can start with the root node, and continually make a new list of nodes until you run out with a simple generator:

```
def make_lists(root):
    current = [root]
    while current:
        yield current
        current = [c for n in current for c in n.children]
    
list(make_lists(nodes['A']))
```

The `while` loop will end when there are no more children, resulting in:

```
[[Node(A)],
 [Node(B), Node(C), Node(D)],
 [Node(E), Node(F), Node(G), Node(H), Node(I), Node(J)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Append each new depth of nodes as a new list.

Start with an empty list: `tree = []`

1. Create a new inner list for the current depth
2. Append each element at the current depth in the list: `tree[depth].append(element)`
3. Go to the next depth and repeat